# Why are these Bootstrap 3 centered text columns not equally top aligned?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to get a layout of Bootstrap columns of text and images to be centered, but I have a strange issue with text columns. They are all centered, but column 2 always drops down:

[image]

I've been parsing all the SO questions about fully centering content in Bootstap 3, but am flummoxed. And I don't want to use Flex or Flexbox; I need the backward compatibility for old browsers.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qqQWwb

```
<div class="row centered">

<div class="col-md-2 col-xs-5"><img class="img-responsive vcenter" src="http://i.imgur.com/1olmVpO.jpg" /></div>
<div class="col-md-2 col-xs-5"><img class="img-responsive vcenter" src="http://i.imgur.com/1olmVpO.jpg" /></div>
<div class="col-md-2 col-xs-5"><img class="img-responsive vcenter" src="http://i.imgur.com/1olmVpO.jpg" /></div>
<div class="col-md-2 col-xs-5"><img class="img-responsive vcenter" src="http://i.imgur.com/1olmVpO.jpg" /></div>

</div>


<div class="row centered">

<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-5">

<h2 class="headline">Column 1</h2>

<p>Nullam nulla risus, lobortis sollicitudin scelerisque quis, varius ac quam. Maecenas condimentum, erat nec dapibus luctus, velit nulla suscipit elit, ac vulputate nulla nulla in elit. Integer nisi purus, faucibus aliquam scelerisque ac, convallis semper ante. Maecenas et nunc eu mi fringilla mattis. Duis commodo, metus eget egestas scelerisque, velit orci malesuada magna, malesuada rhoncus nisi nisl non lorem. Vestibulum ullamcorper nisl at nunc molestie condimentum. Etiam elementum dignissim tincidunt. Donec feugiat tristique est non cursus. Phasellus consequat congue quam ac dictum.</p>
<p>Nullam nulla risus, lobortis sollicitudin scelerisque quis, varius ac quam. Maecenas condimentum, erat nec dapibus luctus, velit nulla suscipit elit, ac vulputate nulla nulla in elit. Integer nisi purus, faucibus aliquam scelerisque ac, convallis semper ante. Maecenas et nunc eu mi fringilla mattis. Duis commodo, metus eget egestas scelerisque, velit orci malesuada magna, malesuada rhoncus nisi nisl non lorem. Vestibulum ullamcorper nisl at nunc molestie condimentum. Etiam elementum dignissim tincidunt. Donec feugiat tristique est non cursus. Phasellus consequat congue quam ac dictum.</p>

</div>

<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-5">

<h2 class="headline">Column 2</h2>

<p>Nullam nulla risus, lobortis sollicitudin scelerisque quis, varius ac quam. Maecenas condimentum, erat nec dapibus luctus, velit nulla suscipit elit, ac vulputate nulla nulla in elit. Integer nisi purus, faucibus aliquam scelerisque ac, convallis semper ante. Maecenas et nunc eu mi fringilla mattis. Duis commodo, metus eget egestas scelerisque, velit orci malesuada magna, malesuada rhoncus nisi nisl non lorem. Vestibulum ullamcorper nisl at nunc molestie condimentum. Etiam elementum dignissim tincidunt. Donec feugiat tristique est non cursus. Phasellus consequat congue quam ac dictum.</p>

</div>

</div>
```

Comment: @morne you can have different column layouts for different screen sizes--as written, the text will be in two columns of width 4 on a medium screen, and two columns of width 5 on an extra-small screen.

Comment: Why are you using `col-md-2` and `col-xs-5` for a row? neither of these add up to 12... Actually, why are you using them at all, if you turn off the float? YOu're using Bootstrap framework, and then turning off the most vital parts of it. IF you remove the `float:none` from the `.centered > div` then you'll see it reverts to how it should be (top aligned)

Comment: Because I want to center everything without adding bootstrap offsets; this is for a client that needs to use bootstrap for a template, with centered and vertical aligned images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give `vertical-align: top` to `col-md-4 col-xs-5` div (in my case I've given it a class named `.col-structure`), like:

```
.col-structure {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below (*view full screen*):

```css
.col-structure {
  vertical-align: top;
}

.centered {
   text-align: center;
}

.centered img {padding:20px;}

.centered > div {
   float: none;
   display: inline-block;
}

.vcenter {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
}

p {text-align: left;}

h2.headline {text-align: center;}

img {max-width:20%}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row centered">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-5">
      <h2 class="headline">headline:</h2> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row centered">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-5"><img class="img-responsive vcenter" src="http://i.imgur.com/1olmVpO.jpg" /> </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-5"><img class="img-responsive vcenter" src="http://i.imgur.com/1olmVpO.jpg" /> </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-5"><img class="img-responsive vcenter" src="http://i.imgur.com/1olmVpO.jpg" /> </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-5"><img class="img-responsive vcenter" src="http://i.imgur.com/1olmVpO.jpg" /> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row centered">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-5 col-structure">
      <h2 class="headline">Column 1</h2>
      <p>Nullam nulla risus, lobortis sollicitudin scelerisque quis, varius ac quam. Maecenas condimentum, erat nec dapibus luctus, velit nulla suscipit elit, ac vulputate nulla nulla in elit. Integer nisi purus, faucibus aliquam scelerisque ac, convallis semper ante. Maecenas et nunc eu mi fringilla mattis. Duis commodo, metus eget egestas scelerisque, velit orci malesuada magna, malesuada rhoncus nisi nisl non lorem. Vestibulum ullamcorper nisl at nunc molestie condimentum. Etiam elementum dignissim tincidunt. Donec feugiat tristique est non cursus. Phasellus consequat congue quam ac dictum.</p>
      <p>Nullam nulla risus, lobortis sollicitudin scelerisque quis, varius ac quam. Maecenas condimentum, erat nec dapibus luctus, velit nulla suscipit elit, ac vulputate nulla nulla in elit. Integer nisi purus, faucibus aliquam scelerisque ac, convallis semper ante. Maecenas et nunc eu mi fringilla mattis. Duis commodo, metus eget egestas scelerisque, velit orci malesuada magna, malesuada rhoncus nisi nisl non lorem. Vestibulum ullamcorper nisl at nunc molestie condimentum. Etiam elementum dignissim tincidunt. Donec feugiat tristique est non cursus. Phasellus consequat congue quam ac dictum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-5 col-structure">
      <h2 class="headline">Column 2</h2>
      <p>Nullam nulla risus, lobortis sollicitudin scelerisque quis, varius ac quam. Maecenas condimentum, erat nec dapibus luctus, velit nulla suscipit elit, ac vulputate nulla nulla in elit. Integer nisi purus, faucibus aliquam scelerisque ac, convallis semper ante. Maecenas et nunc eu mi fringilla mattis. Duis commodo, metus eget egestas scelerisque, velit orci malesuada magna, malesuada rhoncus nisi nisl non lorem. Vestibulum ullamcorper nisl at nunc molestie condimentum. Etiam elementum dignissim tincidunt. Donec feugiat tristique est non cursus. Phasellus consequat congue quam ac dictum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row centered">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-5"><img class="img-responsive vcenter" src="http://i.imgur.com/1olmVpO.jpg" /> </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-5"><img class="img-responsive vcenter" src="http://i.imgur.com/1olmVpO.jpg" /> </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-5"><img class="img-responsive vcenter" src="http://i.imgur.com/1olmVpO.jpg" /> </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-5"><img class="img-responsive vcenter" src="http://i.imgur.com/1olmVpO.jpg" /> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row centered">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-5">
      <h2 class="headline">headline:</h2> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row centered">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-5 col-structure">
      <h2 class="headline">Column 1</h2>
      <p>Nullam nulla risus, lobortis sollicitudin scelerisque quis, varius ac quam. Maecenas condimentum, erat nec dapibus luctus, velit nulla suscipit elit, ac vulputate nulla nulla in elit. Integer nisi purus, faucibus aliquam scelerisque ac, conva llis semper ante. Maecenas et nunc eu mi fringilla mattis. Duis commodo, metus eget egestas scelerisque, velit orci malesuada magna, malesuada rhoncus nisi nisl non lorem. Vestibulum ullamcorper nisl at nunc molestie condimentum. Etiam elementum dignissim tincidunt. Donec feugiat tristique est non cursus. Phasellus consequat congue quam ac dictum.</p>
      <p>Nullam nulla risus, lobortis sollicitudin scelerisque quis, varius ac quam. Maecenas condimentum, erat nec dapibus luctus, velit nulla suscipit elit, ac vulputate nulla nulla in elit. Integer nisi purus, faucibus aliquam scelerisque ac, convallis semper ante. Maecenas et nunc eu mi fringilla mattis. Duis commodo, metus eget egestas scelerisque, velit orci malesuada magna, malesuada rhoncus nisi nisl non lorem. Vestibulum ullamcorper nisl at nunc molestie condimentum. Etiam elementum dignissim tincidunt. Donec feugiat tristique est non cursus. Phasellus consequat congue quam ac dictum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-5 col-structure">
      <h2 class="headline">Column 2</h2>
      <p>Nullam nulla risus, lobortis sollicitudin scelerisque quis, varius ac quam. Maecenas condimentum, erat nec dapibus luctus, velit nulla suscipit elit, ac vulputate nulla nulla in elit. Integer nisi purus, faucibus aliquam scelerisque ac, convallis semper ante. Maecenas et nunc eu mi fringilla mattis. Duis commodo, metus eget egestas scelerisque, velit orci malesuada magna, malesuada rhoncus nisi nisl non lorem. Vestibulum ullamcorper nisl at nunc molestie condimentum. Etiam elementum dignissim tincidunt. Donec feugiat tristique est non cursus. Phasellus consequat congue quam ac dictum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! Works great.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch It's my pleasure!